# Translating a label text on product images in Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, translation, product

I'm designing my first e-commerce. I'm working with woocommerce plugin. I want to translate the label "read more" when I go over the picture of the product [see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GdVr.jpg)

how can i do?
I translated the text on the other button on the left with the instruction

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
    return __( 'Inserisci nel carrello', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

but what is the right one for the "read more" button?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Try the following code that will translate "Read more" in italian, on Woocommerce archive pages:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'read_more_translation', 100, 3 );
function read_more_translation( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if( $text === 'Read more' && is_archive() && is_woocommerce() ) {
        $translated_text =  __( 'Leggi di più', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I tried to insert your code, but the left button has the label "leggi di più" and the right one keep the label "read more". how can I find the name of the "read more" button?

Comment: @Isabella I have updated my answer code… It should do the trick.

Comment: LoicTheAztec you're super! The code work perfectly. thanks a lot.